# Powering on Mikona Android tablet with a broken power button

Tags: buttons, power-on

I have a Mikona Android tablet and the power button has broken quite literally snapped inwards and it has turned fully off. I have opened it up and looked at the circuit and the area around the power button.

How do I turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in the device with no battery and then put the battery back in while it is running.

Also, try plugging in the charger to load the battery bar and then hold all buttons aside from power, it might cause a forced reset and restart into the system like a normal restart.

If none of the above works, try ADB. Use ADB and run the command

```
adb reboot
```

If you can't pick up a device with

```
adb devices
```

Then you'll need to hope they included a V-COM boot before `boot.img`.

To access V-COM You'll need the driver for your device and a flashing program like SP Flash Tool.

- To check for V-COM compatibility, you'll need to open Device Manager as the Administrator on your PC,
- Pull out the battery if removable (if not removable, read below) and plug in the device
- Look carefully for unknown device or V-COM device
- If you hear the computer go beep at all, it's registered a V-COM device

If you don't have a removable battery:

If you don't have a removable battery, then V-COM will only connect for a few seconds and then disconnect when the screen comes on.